# Need to process a file with a random name

Tags: gruntjs

In my case I need to run the uglify task on a file which is processed by the 'rev' task. So normally the configuration for uglify looks like

```
uglify: {
    my_target: {
        files: {
            'dest/input.min.js': ['src/input.js']
        }
    }
}
```

However, because the 'rev' task prepend the file name with a random string, say

```
238029384input.js
```

Is there a way to fix my uglify taks in this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [globbing pattern](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) with a star.

```
uglify: {
    my_target: {
        files: {
            'dest/output.min.js': ['src/*input.js']
        }
    }
}
```

Better yet, can't you just `rev` *after* uglify?

Comment: I changed the question a bit, because I don't want to change the filename. The reason why I want to do a 'rev' first is because I'm using a sourceMap too, and when 'rev' changes the filename, it doesn't work anymore